# When user email is changed copy it to Account

Tags: apex, account, user

I have a requirement to copy the User email to the Account when it is changed, now the issue is when a portal user changes the email, it is not updated in the User until the user verifies by clicking on the link from the email sent by SF.

Comment: What issue are you having here, exactly? Doesn't Salesforce trigger an update to the User record once the User verifies their new email address using the link sent to them?

Comment: @MorganMarchese yes seems like this only, a new email is updated but the trigger does not run

Answer (score 0):

Since the User trigger doesn't execute on verified email address, you have a few options

### Option 1 - (Requires Shield Event Monitoring License)

You can consume the [Platform Event IdentityVerificationEvent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/sforce_api_objects_identityverificationevent.htm) to detect and then invoke Apex or Flow to sync the Account

### Option 2 - Use a scheduled job or schedule-triggered Flow

Here, you scan the Portal user records for mismatches on User.Email and Account.Email; fixing up the Account.Email.  Obviously, there will be delay depending on the schedule settings

### Option 3 - Cross Object Formula field

Change your design so that Account has a lookup relationship to User so the current email is always available to the Account record. You'll need application logic to populate this field when a new Portal user is created but since there's a relationship between [User->Account](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_user.htm?q=user) already, you can exploit that